# How to show image notification in IOS flutter with flutter_local_notifications?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am add FCM image notification support to my project so I am listening messages from firebase and showing with flutter_image_notifications.

for Android it's working with big picture [flutter_local_notifications plugin not showing the big image in notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71053724/flutter-local-notifications-plugin-not-showing-the-big-image-in-notification)
How can we do and do we need to add Ios Notification Service Extension? if yes I need swift program for it

Answer (score 0):

flutter local notification works both for iOS and android
if you configure your project

first do that

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios
2. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/
3. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client

then implement https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

the part about adding image is badly described so it's a main part of code to paste if you want download your image from the web,
the whole point is that you need to provide path in your PHONE FILE SYSTEM where the PICTURE is stored.

```
  final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
"https:PICTURE_ADRESS_IN_THE_WEB.jpg"));

  // Get temporary directory
  final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

  // Create an image name
  var filename = '${dir.path}/image.png';

  // Save to filesystem
  final file = File(filename);
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);


  DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      attachments: [DarwinNotificationAttachment(filename)]);
```